# Using numpy to find area of polygon

Tags: python, numpy, polygon

I have been reading through some python code and have come to this function for the polygon area using numpy.

```
def polygon_area(self, x,y):
        correction = x[-1] * y[0] - y[-1]* x[0]
        main_area = np.dot(x[:-1], y[1:]) - np.dot(y[:-1], x[1:])
        return 0.5*np.abs(main_area + correction)
```

However, I don't quite understand it. Can anyone explain to me why there is a correction of the x and y coordinates and what exactly the function is doing?

Comment: This may answer your question: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon#Area

Answer (score 2):

This is a calculation of the area of a polygon using the shoelace formula. The correction is just the term not calculated in the `main_area` shortcut.

A lot more maths than python or numpy for that matter.

Comment: Are you able to break up the explanation for me? I have no idea how to interpret this function

Comment: Do you understand the maths?

Comment: not entirely no.

Comment: You should take a look at this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shoelace_formula